# LinuxBrew does not install latest version of gcc?

Tags: gcc, compiler-errors, version, sudo, linuxbrew

When I do `g++ --version`on my Linux Ubuntu I get `g++ (Home-brew GCC 5.5.0_7) 5.5.0`. This was installed via `brew install gcc`.

As the latest version of gcc is 10.2, why has brew not installed this version?
I had also tried
`sudo apt update`
`sudo apt install build-essential`
`sudo apt install gcc-9`and
`gcc --version`

but it did not change the version. Any advice?

Also, when I try to run an installation script I get the following error

`error: command 'home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/g++ failed with exit code 1`

but

`which gcc`

gives

`/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/g++`

so I am not sure what happened.